# What happens if user clicks on deep link in the app itself

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io, applinks

If I have created a deep link using the branch.io that opens a specific screen in my app. If this link is also available in my app and a user clicks on it, will it open my screen? or it will do nothing as the link I am trying to open from the app is pointing to the same app?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a Branch link within a webView in your App, you will have to handle the routing to the specific Activity, after reading the Branch link parameters.

Here is a sample Activity which contains a webView and and shows a couple of Branch links. When you click on a link in the webView it reopens the webview and displays the link parameters in a Toast message if a Branch link is clicked

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView_;
    private Button button_;
    private String TAG = "WebViewController";
    private Context context_;
    private static final String URL_TO_LOAD = "https://evangelosg.github.io/index.html";
    private static final String BRANCH_LINK_TO_LOAD = "https://ere6.app.link/b6sS0gsCfG";

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("WebView", "onNewIntent");
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
        branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, referringParams.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(context_, referringParams.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (referringParams.has(BundleExtraKeys.CLICKED_BRANCH_LINK)) {
                        try {
                            boolean clickedBranchLink = referringParams.getBoolean(BundleExtraKeys.CLICKED_BRANCH_LINK);
                            if (clickedBranchLink) {
                                //do stuff!
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.d("BranchTrends", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context_ = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView_ = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView_.setWebViewClient(new BranchWebViewController("app.link", MainActivity.class));
        webView_.loadUrl(URL_TO_LOAD);

        button_ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra("branch", BRANCH_LINK_TO_LOAD);
                customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra("branch_force_new_session", true);
                finish();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(BRANCH_LINK_TO_LOAD));
            }
        });
    }

    public class BranchWebViewController extends WebViewClient {

        private String myDomain_;
        private Class activityToLaunch_;

        BranchWebViewController(@NonNull String myDomain, Class activityToLaunch) {
            myDomain_ = myDomain;
            activityToLaunch_ = activityToLaunch;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();

            if (url.contains(myDomain_)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), activityToLaunch_);
                i.putExtra("branch", url);
                i.putExtra("branch_force_new_session", true);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you read the link parameters you can route to the appropriate Activity based on the link parameters.